# How to check if X seconds has passed in Java?

Tags: c#, java, .net, datetime, time

I know in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) I can do this:

```
DateTime test = DateTime.Now;
if (test >= (pastTime + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)) {
    doSomething();
}
```

What is the Java equivalent?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For this simple check I would advise to simply use the timestamp (in milliseconds) instead of using java.util.Date or some other classes:

```
long test = System.currentTimeMillis();
if(test >= (pastTime + 15*1000)) { //multiply by 1000 to get milliseconds
  doSomething();
}
```

Please note that the `pastTime` variable would also have to be **in milliseconds**.

Unfortunately, there are no suitable "built-in" java classes to deal with time spans. In order to do this, check out the [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) library.

UPDATE: Java 8 introduced the [java.time package](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), use that instead of the external joda time.

Comment: Expanded on this accepted answer's edit about the java.time package in Java 8 in my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

The java time library since JDK8 can do something like:

```
import java.time.Duration
import java.time.Instant

class MyTimeClass {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant then = Instant.now();
        Duration threshold = Duration.ofSeconds(3);
        // allow 5 seconds to pass
        Thread.sleep(5000);        
        assert timeHasElapsedSince(then, threshold) == true;
    }

    public static boolean timeHasElapsedSince(Instant then, Duration threshold) {
        return Duration.between(then, Instant.now()).toSeconds() > threshold.toSeconds();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you can put it in a while cycle. I would implement it in this way.

```
long initTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
boolean timeElapsed = false;
while(timeElapsed){
  if(System.currentTimeMillis - initTime > 15000 ){
    timeElapsed = true
  }else{
    doSomethingElse();
    Thread.sleep(500)
  }
}
doSomething()
```

Comment: Alex's code does to wait until the 15 seconds are over, it only checks _if_ they are over. Misunderstood this as well when I first read it.

Comment: @f1sh Yeah it's true...but usually when you check if an amount of time is over you will redo it until this time is really over...I don't see use cases for checking it only one time. But of corse, this is my opinion ;)

Comment: Its not checked only one time, it is checked a number of times but other actions are performed based on this check during the interim.

Comment: @Alex Yes, you are true...and that's what I mean for doSomethingElse() ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this by using a JodaTime Library in my project.
I came out with this code.

```
String datetime1 = "2012/08/24 05:22:34";
String datetime2 = "2012/08/24 05:23:28";

DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
DateTime time1 = format.parseDateTime(datetime1);
DateTime time2 = format.parseDateTime(datetime2);
Minutes Interval = Minutes.minutesBetween(time1, time2);
Minutes minInterval = Minutes.minutes(5);

if(Interval.isGreaterThan(minInterval)){
  return true;
}
else{
  return false;
}
```

This will check if the `Time` Interval between `datetime1` and `datetime2` `isGreaterThan` 5     `Minutes`. Change the property to `Seconds`. It will be easier for you know.